# DateTime to string format returning incorrect result

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

`((DateTime)somedate).ToString("ddd MMM dd yyyy")` is returning `Tue June 21 2022`

Why not Jun!!!

Comment: What Culture are you using?

Comment: @MarkusMeyer AFAICT, there's no culture that would produce "June" when using the `MMM` format. See: https://rextester.com/EUEHR18903

Comment: @Tony Please [edit] the question and provide a [repro].

Comment: A DateTime always return a number and the same number for each unique time.  The application you are using will display that time differently.  You are seeing the default settings that VS is using.  So if you want to see results differently inside VS you need to change the VS setting used to display the date.  the results ARE CORRECT.

Comment: thanks guys - that's it - the whole culture thing is not in the docs when I quickly read through yesterday - this is perfect (and assumed what stack overflow is for - perhaps not)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### TL;DR;

Use the invariant culture, if you always want to get `Jun`:

```
((DateTime)somedate).ToString("ddd MMM dd yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

### Longer explanation

That's really interesting why [this happens (sometimes)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YTey5.png).

**You should check the values of your `AbbreviatedMonthGenitiveNames` of the culture you're using**.

##### Reproduce it

You can reproduce the behavior, when you use a culture with abbreviated month genitive names that differ from the default:

```
var culture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
culture.DateTimeFormat.AbbreviatedMonthNames = new string[] { "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec", "" };
culture.DateTimeFormat.AbbreviatedMonthGenitiveNames = new string[] { "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "June", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec", "" };

Console.WriteLine(new DateTime(2022, 6, 21).ToString("ddd MMM dd yyyy", culture)); // Tue June 21 2022
```

##### Explanations

There is an explanation [in the documentation of `AbbreviatedMonthGenitiveNames`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.abbreviatedmonthgenitivenames#remarks):

> In some languages, a month name that is part of a date appears in the
> genitive case. For example, a date in the ru-RU or Russian (Russia)
> culture consists of the day number and the genitive month name, such
> as 1 Января (1 January). For these cultures, **if a custom format string
> includes the "MMM" format specifier, the `DateTime.ToString` or `ToString`
> method includes the appropriate member of the
> AbbreviatedMonthGenitiveNames array in place of the "MMM" in the
> result string**.

and [there is an issue](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/68385#issuecomment-1107152290) where this is mentioned too:

> This means when formatting a date containing the day as a number (i.e.
> using `d` or `dd` in the date pattern), then the genitive names will be
> used. As you are using the date pattern `d.MMM.yyyy`, this means the
> date will be formatted using the genitive month names. You will get a
> formatted date something like `1.Jan..2020`. Note the genitive month
> name here is `Jan.` and not `Jan`. If you parse back the formatted string
> `1.Jan..2020` this will be parsed fine. You are not parsing the formatted string instead you are parsing your constructed string
> `1.Jan.2020` which is not a correct form. If you want to get the result you want with de-DE, you may use something like `d.MMMyyyy` or you
> format with day names instead of day number, like `ddd.MMM.yyyy`

##### Possible solution

You could use the invariant culture to get the result you are looking for:

```
new DateTime(2022, 6, 21).ToString("ddd MMM dd yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

This results in: `Tue Jun 21 2022`

Comment: This is useful information and all, but I fail to see how `MMM` could produce "June". Can you provide an example of that? Because it's not shown in any of the examples in [your screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FYo1S.png). See [my comment above](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/128518774) where I iterated all cultures and didn't find any that returns "June" for `MMM`.

Comment: @41686d6564standsw.Palestine I added a reproducable example for that behavior

Comment: @41686d6564standsw.Palestine And yes you are correct - there is no `June` by default. But that doesn't mean that my answer is not correct...

Comment: Sure, I never said the answer was incorrect. But it's a little bit far-fetched to assume the OP has explicitly set the abbreviated month name and then complains about getting the custom-set abbreviated name. It's not impossible though. The previous version of the answer seemed to imply that some _existing_ cultures might return "June", and I was replying to that part.

Comment: Btw. thanks for the hint to add an example to reproduce it (it makes it much clearer I think )